# WHERE IN Subquery - SELECT works but not UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-update

I have the following table on Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE t1(code varchar2(3), flag1 varchar2(30));

INSERT INTO t1(code, flag1) values ('AAA', NULL);    
INSERT INTO t1(code, flag1) values ('BBB', NULL);
```

The Select below works as expected and results 1 row

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t1 
 WHERE code IN (SELECT 'AAA' 
                  FROM DUAL);
```

However the below Update statement does NOT work (it does not update any rows)

```
UPDATE t1
   SET flag1 ='T'
 WHERE code IN (SELECT 'AAA' 
                  FROM DUAL);
```

I am running my tests in sqlfiddle.com (Oracle 11g).

Do you know why this is happening?
I think I am missing something obvious here..

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me.

Comment: You are missing something, but I don't know what because - that `update` actually **updates** 1 row.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the sub-select is totally useless. `where code in ('AAA')` would work just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course it is useless :) I am just using a minimal  example here

Comment: @Mat I am testing this in http://sqlfiddle.com (Oracle 11g)

Comment: sqlfiddle should not be used for testing IMO, as it doesn't function exactly the same as a database engine sometimes

Comment: And how is this not working in sqlfiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0096c9/5

Comment: @NenadZivkovic strange :/ I will try again..

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I probably do not know how to use SQLFiddle, I was running the commands separately and not as script. Re-test and it works.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic EXISTS is better than IN when comparing a subquery

Comment: @Athafoud SqlFiddle does not persist data, every time you run the script, it shows result and rolls back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems from the comment discussion this in not a Programming related issue, since I was not completely aware how the SQLFiddle works / behaves.

I was wrongly running the commands (`SELECT` -> `UPDATE` -> `SELECT`), each separately by its own and not as a batch. Meaning that the changes from my `UPDATE` statement where not 'visible' in the subsequent `SELECT`.

In conclusion

> SqlFiddle does not persist data, every time you run the script, it shows result and rolls back

Special **thanks** to [Nenad Zivkovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612181/nenad-zivkovic) and [WhatsThePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7147233/whatsthepoint) for helping me conclude to the *'solution'*.

Answer (score 0):

tried using exists?

```
UPDATE t1
   SET flag1 ='T'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM DUAL WHERE code = 'AAA');
```

Comment: What does the subquery return? Will the UPDATE update all rows or no rows?

Comment: the subquery returns a boolean. It will update row(s) that has code = 'AAA' if true, otherwise it will not update.

Comment: For all t1 rows, the EXISTS will be true if DUAL has a row with code = 'AAA'. If DUAL has no such row, the EXISTS will always be false. I.e. either all t1 rows will be updated, or no t1 rows will be updated - depending on DUAL has a code = 'AAA' row or not.